# Making a template for Many ViewCotrollers

Tags: swift, xcode, user-interface, storyboard, viewcontroller

I was just wondering how to make a template for many `viewcontrollers`. I am asking that because i have a `tableViewController` and DynamicProperties `TableViewCells` and each one opens a sepereate `ViewController` as a profile page of the `cell`. So my question is how do I make a single `UI` template to all of these `ViewControllers` or do i have to do the `UI` 1 by 1 to all of these "Profile pages".

Comment: So you have something like a list of people and selecting one you want to see their profile? This is called a master detail interface.

Comment: Exactly ! Sorry for my bad explanation...

Comment: If i add my Code can you help me Integrate such function into my project i really must have this.. :( ? i cant find any good tutorial explaining it :/

Comment: I have a tabbed bar application and i really need to know how to do this master detail like interface. please